# How do I read from one column to another on one line?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a def__init__(self, message, score) function
I want to compare if self.message.score > self.message.score.

How do I have the python program only loop once, read from column - column on the same line, and return me the one with the greater value? Thank you for reading and answering this.

Comment: please show us what you have so far.

Comment: `if self.message.score > self.message.score` will never return `True`.

Comment: @usr2564301 I know. But I want to just read the first self.message.score. Oh, and message != message or else it cannot work.

Comment: Well, `message != message` is not going to work either. But your question seems far from complete, so maybe it'll work after all. We need more information than you have provided so far.

Comment: @usr2564301 Ok. If I do an “if self.message.score > self.message.score”, how do I include the argument/parameter: “self.message != self.message” because I do not want the program to compare the message id to the same message Id.

Comment: Why don't you describe what the problem you're solving is.  Your attempts to explain your proposed solution to your problem don't make much sense. Maybe include some sample messages and a description of what your bot should do with them?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh ok. Every time the client posts a message in a channel specific channel, the bot replies and adds thumbsup and thumbsdown reactions. It counts the reactions as a string, and subtracts them. I use def __init__ command to create the the format that I want for my library. self = discord.client, self.message = client.messages, and self.message.score = ‘score’. Now I want to compare if self.message.score > self.message.score. Argument: self.message != self.message